# When to use Redirect::action over a Redirect::route?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Seems that I can achieve what I want to happen using either of the 2 approaches above. So why is `Redirect::action` implemented and when is the best time to use this response?

Comment: If you have restrictions on routes such as authentication, etc then it's better to go`::route` rather than skipping straight to the controller.

Comment: @Matt so redirecting straight to the action will not trigger filters or middlewares? Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnnyQ its just another method of resolving what url you want. Doesn't change the way requests work.